# Elements are moving outside of container in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a looping video header that I implemented using a snippet of code I found. I overlaid text and a button on top of it. It looks alright until I get to a certain break point, and then the text and button move outside of the video container.

I tried putting into the div that I thought the video was in, but it just removed the text and button from view altogether.

The site is kgshowroom.com/test and it's the coral-colored "Hello" button and text that says "KG Showroom You're on our site".

This is the code I think I'm supposed to be tweaking:

**(Video Container?)**

```
<div class="header-video">
    <img src="img/masthead.jpg"
         class="header-video--media"
         data-video-src="0CxWLQxvY9g"
         data-teaser-source="video/masthead-teaser"
         data-provider="Youtube"
         data-video-width="500"
         data-video-height="281">
    <a href="http://vimeo.com/87701971">


  </div>
```

**(Text and Button Section?)**

```
<div id="header">
      <!-- Inner -->
        <div class="inner" style="position: relative; z-index: 999; top: 0px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
          <header>
            <h1>
               <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/KG-logo.png"><br />KG Showroom</a></h1>
            <p>You're on our site.</p>
          </header> 

          <footer>
            <a href="#banner" class="button circled scrolly">Hello!</a>
          </footer>

        </div>
```

I tried moving the "Text and Button Section" into the place above the closing div tag in the "Video Container" but it just made the Text and Button disappear.

Anyone know where I am going wrong on this? I want it to stay overlaid and centered on the video on all breakpoints, no matter the size of the screen.

Additionally, the looping video plays on my Samsung Note II, but it doesn't play on my brother's Samsung Galaxy (5?). It plays all the way through the different sizes on my desktop when testing; is there something in the code that is making it not work on my brother's phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an issue with CSS, not HTML. The text and button are just too big. Depending on how your CSS is handling sizes, I would play with making some of the stacked elements in the header smaller (logo, menu, text, button), or re-arrange the layout for mobile. Or if you're ok with having things overlap, use absolute positioning or negative margins.

Comment: Thanks, @rblakeley! I'm really new to all of this, so it's hard for me to know where/how to pinpoint the problems. Also, do you know why this post would have been downvoted? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I have no idea why it's down-voted. I've given answers with tiny, non-critical errors, which get belabored in the comments. I'll fix those errors and they never retract the down-vote. [Haterz gon hate](http://gifs.joelglovier.com/haters-gonna-hate/haters-gonna-hate-futurama.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the smile, @rblakeley! :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `HeaderVideo` function in `script.js` is dynamically resizing the `header-video`class which explains your sizing issues. You might want to rework the logic in that function or utilize [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Thanks, @gffbss — I'll look into that. I'm not really familiar with javascript (been ages since I took the course on it), so I'll do my research on it.